# Is there any kind of API which allows to get the profile information?

Tags: support, flair, api, combined-flair

I want to include a tag or kind of business card on my homepage where a link to my account, my current reputation and my current badges are show. Could be something like the user card under a question or answer:

> [image: My user card for meta.stackoverflow.com]

Is there an API for this or is it allowed to parse it from the Stack Overflow website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550184/paedow/flair) is what you are looking for.
Like this one:

[image: profile for Paedow at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

As @Sha Wiz Dow Ard suggested on his [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151648/is-there-any-kind-of-stckoverflow-api-which-allows-to-get-the-profile-informatio#comment435129_151649):
[Global flair is also available.](https://stackexchange.com/users/1687146/paedow?tab=flair)
Like this one:

[image: profile for Paedow on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Related blog: [Flair: Now Even Flairier](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/)

Comment: Yeah, that´s perfect thanks :)

Comment: Yup, and you also have [global flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/1687146/paedow?tab=flair) available. @Paedow - TYI as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to write customer queries that can get different info. For instance, a [query for your user info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1550184&filter=!9ciXf0Jql&site=stackoverflow&run=true) returns:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "user_id": 1550184,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "creation_date": 1343176618,
      "display_name": "Paedow",
      "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e87fbc64060164fc6663e28896a3f6d2?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
      "reputation": 850,
      "reputation_change_day": 0,
      "reputation_change_week": 0,
      "reputation_change_month": 12,
      "reputation_change_quarter": 12,
      "reputation_change_year": 120,
      "age": 17,
      "last_access_date": 1381063242,
      "last_modified_date": 1380739628,
      "is_employee": false,
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1550184/paedow",
      "website_url": "http://e-volution-software.de/",
      "location": "Germany",
      "account_id": 1687146,
      "badge_counts": {
        "gold": 0,
        "silver": 7,
        "bronze": 31
      },
      "question_count": 40,
      "answer_count": 22,
      "up_vote_count": 473,
      "down_vote_count": 5,
      "about_me": "",
      "view_count": 159,
      "accept_rate": 100
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 9994,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

You can use this to get certain pieces of information that are not available through the standard flair, although you have to format it all nice and fancy-like, and go through another few hoops.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your own flair in your profile page, under Edit Profile & Settings -> Flair:

[image]